# Unexpected matlab expression in function

Tags: matlab, function, call

I have the following call to a function:

```
callfun(I1, I2, [X Y ones(n,1)], w, m)
```

But, I'm getting:

```
Error: File: callfun.m Line: 20 Column: 3
Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says, that your function `callfun` has a syntax error in line 20. Probably some character which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be also a problem of duplicated function definition. A function inside callfun.m may have the same name as a built-in MATLAB function, what yields an error.

From http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/214993-how-to-solve-error-unexpected-matlab-expression-workspacefunc-287:

> Do you have any user-defined functions called builtin, strjoin, or strsplit? MATLAB has these defined internally, and having any outside functions that shadow these built-in ones would result in this error. If you are unsure if you have created such functions, typing the command:

```
>>which functionName -all
```

> will show you the path to all items on the MATLAB path with the name "functionName"